# .mask with .toUpperCase() for Postcodes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use the following .mask

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#postcode').mask('a9a 9a9');

});
```

But also on every Key stroke force the lower case to be uppercase but to also allow lowercase to be entered (I didn't just want to set the definition of the mask to be always uppercase), this is what i tried so far without success (it kinda works but doesn't keep the cursor position)

```
$("#postcode").keyup(function (e) {

            var this2 = $('#postcode').val().toUpperCase();

             $('#postcode').val(this2);

         });
```

Comment: dont use `this` as a variable name   ...ever! Stay away from reserved words. Why are you using 2 different methods on same element to modify value? Just use the plugin API methods

Comment: @charlietfl which API method can I use to achieve this then? have masking and forced capitalization for postcodes.

Comment: haven't used that plugin in years, look through the source and/or docs

Comment: @charlietfl - helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround by adding this to the text box:

```
style="text-transform: uppercase"
```

Comment: But this only displays uppercase. The actual value is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `this` is already defined in the scope of the `keyup` event and probably causing your problem when you assign it.  This version retains the cursor position.

working version on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/threadid/cqz5khyr/)

```
$("#postcode").keyup(function () {

    var ucase = $(this).val().toUpperCase()
    $(this).val(ucase);

 });
```

Comment: That doesn't retain the cursor position, it moves it to the end.

Comment: @nnnnnn   That is the normal behavior of an input field.

Comment: Yeah this is what mine was doing with the masking as well this doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better solution:

```
$(".editor-template__value").keyup(function (e) {
     var start = e.target.selectionStart;
     e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
     e.target.selectionStart = e.target.selectionEnd = start;
});
```

You text will change to Uppercase and cursor position won't be changing.